# How can we get the caret cursor position on macOS using the Accessibility API?

Tags: swift, macos

In macOS Sonoma, a mic icon appears when dictation is used, hovering over the cursor in the focused text field. To find the x, y position of the caret?

I've tried using underlying accessibility api to get the focused element and get the caret but I keep getting nothing on the position end, here's my code snippet.

```
    private func getFocusedUIElement() {
        let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
        var focusedElement: AnyObject?
        let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &focusedElement)

        if result == .success, let focusedElement = focusedElement as! AXUIElement? {
            getCaretScreenPosition(focusedElement: focusedElement)
        } else {
            print("Failed to get the focused element or no focused element.")
        }
    }

    private func getCaretScreenPosition(focusedElement: AXUIElement) {
        var selectedTextRangeValue: AnyObject?
        let selectedTextRangeResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, &selectedTextRangeValue)

        if selectedTextRangeResult == .success, let selectedTextRangeValue = selectedTextRangeValue {
            var selectedTextRange = CFRange()
            // Directly bridge to AXValue without conditional casting
            let axValue: AXValue = selectedTextRangeValue as! AXValue
            if AXValueGetType(axValue) == .cfRange, AXValueGetValue(axValue, .cfRange, &selectedTextRange) {
                // The range retrieval was successful; now attempt to get the caret position
            }
        }

        var caretPositionValue: AnyObject?
        let positionResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement, kAXPositionAttribute as CFString, &caretPositionValue)

        if positionResult == .success, let positionAXValue = caretPositionValue {
            // Directly bridge to AXValue, handling the optional with a forced cast since we've already checked for success
            let axPositionValue: AXValue = positionAXValue as! AXValue
            var caretPositionPoint = CGPoint.zero
            if AXValueGetType(axPositionValue) == .cgPoint, AXValueGetValue(axPositionValue, .cgPoint, &caretPositionPoint) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    // Update the caret position on the main thread
                    self?.caretPosition = caretPositionPoint
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to get the caret screen position.")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get the caret position.")
        }
    }
```